# Flutter version solving failed on google_maps_flutter while running "flutter pub get"

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, flutter-packages

I'm getting below message in output while running `flutter pub get` even though I've downgraded google map package to `google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.33` which is `<1.0.0`.

```
[proj_name] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in proj_name...                    
The current Flutter SDK version is 1.22.0-9.0.pre.

Because proj_name depends on google_maps_flutter >=1.0.0 which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.22.0 <2.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because proj_name depends on google_maps_flutter >=1.0.0 which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.22.0 <2.0.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

Code snippet of `pubspec.yaml`

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.33
```

Result of `flutter --version`

```
Flutter 1.22.0-9.0.pre • channel unknown • unknown source
Framework • revision 7a43175198 (3 months ago) • 2020-08-28 23:18:04 -0400
Engine • revision 07e2520d5d
Tools • Dart 2.10.0 (build 2.10.0-73.0.dev)
```

Comment: update map lib version to `1.0.6` and switch to stable version of flutter sdk by `flutter channel stable`

Comment: Removing the ^ in pubspec.yaml declaration solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the ^ in pubspec.yaml declaration

`google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.33` to `google_maps_flutter: '0.5.33'`

If I'm not mistaken, the ^ means take this version or higher.

Answer (score 6):

Follow up the steps:

`flutter channel stable`

`flutter upgrade`

Then Try again if you get the same error then

just change in your `pubspec.yaml file:` from this
`google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.33`
to this
`google_maps_flutter:`

It will automatically work as it will find out the version which is compatible itself.

Answer (score 0):

Update flutter version to 2.0.2 stable then clean and run app, this will solve issue